# fetching model's inner attribute value into backbonejs frontend

Tags: jquery, html, mongodb, backbone.js

how to retrieve `$oid` value from model object(mentioned below) onto backbonjs index.html file. note that I am using mongodb in the backend.

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "570bd04703cfd2b80d000001"} },....}
```

`<td><%= htmlEncode(modelobject.get('$oid')) %></td>`-->
 did not work

`<td><%= htmlEncode(modelobject.get('_id')) %></td>` --->
returns [object][object] on the frontend.

Comment: Why is the mangodb id thing coming directly as an object to the client side... I don't think it should. You should be sending the string representation  to client side... then it'll show correctly

Comment: did you try <td><%= htmlEncode(modelobject.get('_id')['$oid']) %></td>

Comment: Many thanks nikhil for that one.. simple an effective

Comment: @TJ .. when i use node js this oid thing does not come up... but when calling from java this oid creates a mess... but loving it now...added mongodb here so that people who faced similar issue my help me quicker :)..."Why is the mangodb id thing coming directly as an object to the client side" i dont know how to do that sir.. if you u have any suggestion please share